# Syntax error on a onclick event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I want to transfer some informations to my Google Analytics account, to get informations about my site. But I have one problem. I always get in the console:

```
(index):2513 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
```

This is my `onclick=".."` line:

```
<a onclick="googleAL(https://www.gamesdeal.com/south-park-the-fractured-but-whole-pc.html?___store=english?a_aid=gmkshp, South Park The Fractured But Whole);" href="https://www.gamesdeal.com/south-park-the-fractured-but-whole-pc.html?___store=english?a_aid=gmkshp" title="South Park The Fractured But Whole" class="btn btn-buy btn-sm btn-block" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Kaufen*</a>
```

But the straing thing is that it is working with another function:

```
<a onclick="fbPixels();" href="https://www.gamesdeal.com/south-park-the-fractured-but-whole-pc.html?___store=english?a_aid=gmkshp" title="South Park The Fractured But Whole" class="btn btn-buy btn-sm btn-block" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Kaufen*</a>
```

So I think, the reason **why it is not working must be** the googleAL function:

```
onclick="googleAL(https://www.gamesdeal.com/south-park-the-fractured-but-whole-pc.html?___store=english?a_aid=gmkshp, South Park The Fractured But Whole);"
```

But where is my error? - Why throws this line a error? I don't se the error...

The function doesn't even gets called... I know that, because I do not get a alert. Where is the error in this line?

The googleAL function looks like:

```
<script>
        function googleAL(url, title) {
            alert("Hello" . url, title);
            ga('send', 'event', {
                    eventCategory: 'lead',
                    eventAction: title,
                    eventLabel: url
            });
        }
</script>
```

Greetings and Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

String values need to be enclosed in quotes.

So instead of this:

```
googleAL(http://...)
```

You'd want this:

```
googleAL('http://...')
```

Each argument would be its own string in this case, too:

```
googleAL('http://...', 'South Park...')
```

Comment: And how can I enclose strings in quotes in my code? - With `\\' . $url . \\'`?

Comment: @FrazeJr.: By putting quotes around the string values.  It's not really clear what the problem is at this point, or what you're trying to illustrate there.

Comment: My code looks like this at the moment: `'<a  onclick="googleAL(\'\" .$url. \' ", \\"'.get_the_title($post_id).'\\");" '</a>';` -> But the quotes aren't working!

Comment: @FrazeJr.: That looks like PHP, which isn't mentioned at all in the question.  Do note that mixing *three languages* on a single line of code is just asking for quoting errors.  Ideally you'll want to separate some of these, perhaps by separating out the JavaScript and attaching the click handler to the element from JavaScript instead of inline in the HTML.  But aside from that, "the quotes aren't working" isn't really descriptive.  What *is* being created by that PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this with correct syntax.

You should enclose with quotes, but now there are string.
If you want to change type of data, change into your function in javascript.

```
<a onclick="googleAL('https://www.gamesdeal.com/south-park-the-fractured-but-whole-pc.html?___store=english?a_aid=gmkshp', 'South Park The Fractured But Whole');" href="https://www.gamesdeal.com/south-park-the-fractured-but-whole-pc.html?___store=english?a_aid=gmkshp" title="South Park The Fractured But Whole" class="btn btn-buy btn-sm btn-block" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">Kaufen*</a>
```